# How Do I Get A Div to Completely Clear When I Toggle?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, toggle

I'm attempting to have a div that runs split screen. The left panel will have multiple links, so the simple toggle I am using is ineffective. I need to be able to clear out the right div and replace it with the next selected link. (Something similar to this
https://www.itriagehealth.com/conditions) Right now, it just stacks the selected links.

I  realized I can't do this with CSS alone and am still playing with javascript, but this is the concept I have so far:

https://jsfiddle.net/od9bnez4/1/

```
function toggle_visibility(id) 
{
   var e = document.getElementById(id);   
if (e.style.display == 'block')   
   e.style.display = 'none';
else
   e.style.display = 'block';
 }
```

Comment: _“still playing with [J]ava”_ — not seeing, where you are using Java.

Answer (score 0):

That fiddle should work, there's just an error in your function declaration, missing the closing brace `}`, and then change the JavaScript execution (with the gear next to 'JavaScript') to run as a tag in the `<head>` or `<body>`, not sure why onLoad isn't working there.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will do the trick, https://jsfiddle.net/od9bnez4/3/

The heart of it is this,

```
var left = document.getElementById("left");
var div1 = document.getElementById("div1");
var div2 = document.getElementById("div2");

left.addEventListener('click', function() {
    if (div1.style.display == "none") {
    div1.style = "display: block;";
    div2.style = "display: none;";
  } else {
    div1.style = "display: none;";
    div2.style = "display: block;";
  }
});
```

Obviously this only works for two elements and is very procedural. Typically someone would use something like jQuery for this, or even a framework like Angular or React to build a modularized component.

Answer (score -1):

This is pretty easy. JQuery makes it more flexible.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script>
    function toggle()
    {
      var e = document.getElementById('diva');
      var f = document.getElementById('divb');
      if (f.style.display == 'none')
      {
        e.style.display = 'none';
        f.style.display = 'block';
      }
      else
      {
        f.style.display = 'none';
        e.style.display = 'block';
      }
    }
    function togglejquery()
    {
      if ($('#divb').css('display') == 'none')
      {
        $('#diva').hide();  // or slideUp('fast');
        $('#divb').show();  // or slideDown('fast');
      }
      else
      {
        $('#divb').hide();
        $('#diva').show();
      }
    }

    </script>
    </head>

    <body onload="positionScreenBottom();">
     <div style="float:left; width:40%;">
     <a href='#' onclick='toggle();'>Show A</a><br/>
     <a href='#' onclick='toggle();'>Show B</a><br/>
     </div>
     <div style="float:left; width:60%;">
     <div id='diva' style='float:left;'>Here is A</div>
     <div id='divb' style='float:left; display:none;'>Here is B</div>
     </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```